# JSON парсинг из vimeo

Tags: java, android, json, vimeo, gson

В приложении, пользователь имеет возможность вставлять разные url(видео к примеру `https://vimeo.com/185441790`) с vimeo.

Появилась необходимость спарсить c помощью JSON, но уже с такой ссылки, аналогичной выше `https://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/183364240.json`, чтоб потом можно было получить thumbnail url с него.

С JSON знаком поверхностно, набрёл на интересный пример c: [www.androidhive.info](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/).
Но тут как мне кажется много лишнего, не могли бы Вы меня пожалуйста сориентировать в нужном направлении(работаю во фрагменте).

- Нужно ли создавать дополнительно класс HttpHandler.java как показано в примере или можно поместить всё в один?
- Так как мне эти данные никуда в принципе выводить не надо, а только получить url, то возможно ли сократить свой запрос?
- В примере указана ссылка из которой и берутся в принципе все данные, у меня это ресурс vimeo.com, как правильно указать его в переменной url, и если у меня ссылки из данного ресурса будут всегда разные, будет ли отрабатывать корректно.
- Возможно лучше будет создать объект-модели и используя Gson парсить мой url?

Answer (score 2):

Для вашего случая JSON можно достать так:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
String url = ((JSONObject)jsonArray.get(0)).getString("thumbnail_small");
```

Comment: Спасибо за реакцию, но помимо этого понимаю ещё нужен какой то метод прописать? не очень понимаю как в "одиночку" это работает. Вы делаете якобы запрос и получаете в ответ массив верно? а как я могу его дальше использовать, поясните пожалуйста, если нетрудно.

Comment: @VadimMorozov, Для начала, вам нужно получить JSON, который находится по ссылке, и записать его в переменную, например `String jsonString;`. Дальше использовать мой код, который из полученного JSONа достает ссылку на картинку. Дальше с этой ссылкой вы можете делать все, что хотите

Comment: а получить  JSON каким способом удобней получать, не подскажете?

Comment: @VadimMorozov, JSON - это обычный текст. Есго можно загрузить, как любой текст. Найти ответ на ваш вопрос проще простого, у вас получится, я в вас верю. Просто если я и это за вас сделаю, то пользы не будет никакой.

Comment: возможно ли это реализовать посредством retrofit'a?
вроде как должен сокращать код, учитывая что данную библиотеку использую в проекте.

Comment: @VadimMorozov, да, можно.